# Android Async Task Do in Background Error

Tags: android

Am trying to create an activity that connects to a database on my local host, after the user fills the form the form is submitted to the localhost using an asyntask.do in background method. Am getting an error and am not quite sure what is wrong, Please i need help.

this is my logcat

```
  `01-30 06:03:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1332): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    01-30 06:03:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1332): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-30 06:03:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
01-30 06:03:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
01-30 06:03:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
01-30 06:03:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
01-30 06:03:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-30 06:03:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
01-30 06:03:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-30 06:03:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-30 06:03:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-30 06:03:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1332): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-30 06:03:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at com.oose.buddiev2.RegisterActivity$CreateNewUser.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:101)
01-30 06:03:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at com.oose.buddiev2.RegisterActivity$CreateNewUser.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:1)
01-30 06:03:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
01-30 06:03:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-30 06:03:10.451: E/AndroidRuntime(1332):     ... 5 more`
```

this is my async task in the activity

```
class CreateNewUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RegisterActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating User..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating User
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        String usernameString = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
        String emailString = emailEditText.getText().toString();
        String passwordString = passwordEditText.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", usernameString));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", emailString));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", passwordString));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_user,
                "POST", params);

        // check logcat for response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            // int success = 1;

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: What's the line 101 of your RegisterActivity.java?

Comment: You got Nullpointer exception at line 101 in RegisterActivity.java. Just check what it is, u can solve this issue.

Comment: this is line 101:
    String passwordString = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
i commented it out and removed the `startactivity` in the do in background, n it woked just fine, but how am i supposed to pass the password string to sever. because it looks like am doin it wrong

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in doInBackground.

Try by removing this from doInBackground or you can put this in OnPostExecute():

```
startActivity(i);
finish();
```